# Odata Url conversion with descending orderby

Tags: odata, odata4j

i need to get data by descending orderby Visidate of patient so i tried url like this

```
192.168.1.105:33396/FalconCPDataService.svc/DEPhysicians?$format=json&$expand=DEPatientVisits&$orderby=DEPatientVisits/VisitDate+desc
```

but showing exception

{"odata.error":{"code":"","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The parent value for a property access of a property 'VisitDate' is not a single value. Property access can only be applied to a single value."}}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that DEPatientVisits is not a single valued navigation property, so it is unable to append a property name to it. If it is a single valued, it works fine, such as:

```
http://services.odata.org/v4/OData/OData.svc/Products?$expand=Supplier&$orderby=Supplier/Name
```

Comment: if use "**expand**" i am getting this exception without this it works fine @tanjinfu

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for inviting.

I am not fully understand your question. you want to sort entities in DEPhysicians? or DEPatientVisits?

If you are try to get DEPhysicians inline expand DEPatientVisits, and want sort entities in **DEPatientVisits** by VisitDate, you can try:

```
locolhost/FalconCPDataService.svc/DEPhysicians?$format=json&$expand=DEPatientVisits($orderby=VisitDate desc)
```

If you are try to sort entities in DEPhysicians according to DEPatientVisits\VisitDate, then, just as the answer from @tanjinfu, DEPatientVisits should not be a collection. Otherwise, which VisitDate of entry in DEPatientVisits you want to used to sort?

Comment: thanks @Maya i tried url which one you gave to me but it showing {"odata.error":{"code":"","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Term 'DEPatientVisits($orderby=VisitDate desc)' is not valid in a $select or $expand expression."}}}

Answer (score 0):

I did this in the call to the odata.
g?$orderby=Date_and_Time%20desc

which gave me my records in descending order from the table.